# Why does this keep displaying the menu?- python

Tags: python

I am trying to make something that gives you a menu if you enter in m, and continues if you just press enter.

```
menu = False
while True:
    option = input('Press M for menu, and press enter to continue')
    if option == 'm' or 'M':
        menu = True
        while menu:
            print('MENU')
            #theres some stuff here but thats not important
    else:
        print('Continuing...')
```

But, whenever I run this, it always goes to the menu screen.

Comment: check `if option == 'm' or 'M':` again. It will evaluate `'M'` as True. `if option == 'm' or option == 'M':`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if option == 'm' or 'M'
```

Here `option == 'm' or 'M'` is a boolean expression which always evaluates to True, since `'M'` will always be not None. Just change it to

```
if option.lower()=='m':
```